# basic sharepoint workflow access denied even though I'm admin and owner

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, workflow, wss-3.0

I have created a very basic workflow in SPD 2007 - for testing, I've narrowed it down to 1 step, " if 1 equals 1, send an email to myself."  also tried having it just update a field on that listitem.  Very simple!  I then save it, but when I go to a list item to run the workflow manually, I get an Access Denied error, currently signed in as myself.

This is weird because the account that access is denied is 1)site collection admin, 2) member of owners group, 3) the account that created and saved the workflow.

I am completely stumped!  All ideas are welcome.

Thank you!!

Comment: have u checked your permissions on the list and the item on which you are executing the workflow

Comment: yup!  Everything's inheriting from the site and I am owner of the site.  I am also site collection admin which should give me access to everything anyways.  Also, I am the one who created the site, list, items, and workflow.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you are accessing SP as an annonymous user, even though you are logged into windows as a site admin.

You may also get problems if you access the site using localhost instead of the machine name.

The other thing to check is if there are errors in the SP log file or the event log.